# C# WebAPI - getting URL with parameters passed as QueryString

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, controller, urlencode

I've been searching for this problem but non was identical to my case.

I have the following controller:

```
 public HttpResponseMessage GetMyService(int aType, [FromUri] string streamURL)
```

**streamURL** is a parameter that gets a full URL sent by the client.

The client calls the service like that:
*http://www.myservice.com/.../GetMyService/?aType=1&streamURL=http://www.client.com/?p1=100&p2=200*

The problem is that at then end, I get the **[FromUri] string streamURL** parameter as http://www.client.com/?**p1=100** without the **&p2=200**

This is known and reasonable, but I cannot place any encoding/decoding functionality as the URL is cut at the very beginning.

Any help would be appreciated..

THX

Comment: The client should encode the URL before it gets sent to your service where it can then be decoded and used as appropriate. I don't think there's much your service can do since as it stands it can't tell the difference between a new querystring parameter and the continuation of the URL sent from the client.

Comment: The `streamURL` value needs to be Url Encoded by the calling client

Comment: How is the client making the request? What is the client? provide a [mcve] that can be used to reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 3):

The client should properly [`URL encode`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Percent-encoding) the value of the `streamURL` query string parameter when making the request in order to conform to the HTTP protocol specification:

```
http://www.myservice.com/.../GetMyService/?aType=1&streamURL=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.client.com%2F%3Fp1%3D100%26p2%3D200
```

So basically there's nothing you could do on the server side, you should fix the client.